Wix Toolset, skip selection after license agreement
I have made a small installation in Wix3.11, and the idea was to run the welcome dialog, then license, then ready.
Using the following code, I can go from Welcome dialog to ready dialog and back, but I cannot set the License dialog to go directly to the Ready dialog.
It is just being ignored. I checked spelling, that should be correct.
Can I go from License to Ready dialog?
The odd thing is, that going back is not a problem
My code:
<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="license.rtf" />
<WixVariable Id="WixUISupportPerUser" Value="0" />
<UI Id="MyWixUI_Mondo">      
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />

  <!-- this will work -->
  <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg" >1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg" >1</Publish>

  <!-- this will not have any affect -->
  <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="2">
    LicenseAccepted = "1"</Publish>
  <!-- however, going "back" works, but not with the previous line included: -->
  <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg" >1</Publish>

I have looked at WixUI_Mondo.wxs, and there I find:
<Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg">
  NOT Installed AND NOT PATCH</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">
  Installed AND PATCH</Publish>

<Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="SetupTypeDlg" Order="2">
  LicenseAccepted = "1"</Publish>

With that in mind, I assume that I am doing it right, but it cannot be changed.

Maybe the problem is in collision of that string in your code
<Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="2">
    LicenseAccepted = "1"</Publish>

and that one in WixUI_Mondo (which is referenced in your code)
<Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="SetupTypeDlg" Order="2">
  LicenseAccepted = "1"</Publish>

try to change Order="2" in your code to Order="1".
But in your case it's better to write all Publish element by yourself, without referencing WixUI_Mondo. Use WixUI_Mondo.wxs file as example.

Your answer was not the right one, but you brought me to the right path. I studied the mondo.wxs and other filers, and you are right about the Order.
Setting it to 999 will do the trick
Thanks for making me think. I needed that

Thanks to @Kirumata I found the answer. It is the Order property of Publish that does the trick, when I set it 999 then it will override the default value from Mondo.
The full code for having Welcome - License (which we use for information) and then Ready is as follows:
  <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="license.rtf" />
  <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="TOP_LEVEL_DIR" />
  <UI Id="MyWixUI_Mondo">
    <Property Id="LicenseAccepted" Value="1" />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />
    <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog"
      Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="999">LicenseAccepted = "1"</Publish>      
    <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog"
      Value="LicenseAgreementDlg">1</Publish>
  </UI>

